# Remove root directory from file name with preg_match

Tags: php, preg-replace

This is probably a super-easy thing do to, although I can't seem to get it right.I've also searched around a bit and can't seem to find an answer.

I'm trying to remove the root directory from `$url` string.

Here's my code:

```
<?php

    $files =  glob( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/files/*');

    $root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/files/';

    foreach($files as $file)
    {
       $name = preg_replace("$root", "", $file);
       echo "$name";
    }

?>
```

Comment: When using regex, you need to specify delimiters and an extra measurement `'#' . preg_quote($root, '#') . '#'`. Also it supports several input, so there's no need to put it in a loop. It's extremely slow to put a `preg_*` function in a loop. You might as well use `str_replace` for this task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str_replace()` instead, like this:

```
$name = str_replace("$root", "", $file);
```

Also, the double quotes aren't necessary. You could do like this to save (minor) execution time:

```
$name = str_replace($root, '', $file);
```

(PHP will parse text in double quotes to look for variables. In this case you can clarify directly that there IS a variable in there and nothing else. The text that it should be replaced with is empty (no need for parsing there).

Comment: No problem. I've re-written the code a little bit. Check the latest version :-)

Comment: Tested the code now. The second version is *0,0000272 seconds* faster. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [basename](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php):

```
$name = basename($file);
```